# Минутка развлекательных вопросов pixijs

Tags: javascript, jquery, разработка-игр

Как сделать так чтобы патрон вылетал с каким то промежутком времени, сейчас он вылетает как только попадает в цель. Первая мысль сделать счетчик, так как отрисовывается 60 кадров в секунду то 60 итераций счетчика будет примерно равны одной секунде, в теории. Но что если количество кадров станет меньше. 
http://codepen.io/korolariya/pen/VvwYvr

```
this.attack = function() {
    if (!this.bullet) {
        console.log('Заряжаю');
        this.bullet = new bullet();
        this.bullet.body.position = {
            x: this.body.position.x,
            y: this.body.position.y
        };
        this.bullet.target = this.target;
    } else {
        if (this.bullet.distance < 10) {
            if (mobs[this.index_target].hp > 0) {
                mobs[this.index_target].hp -= 1;
            } else {
                stage.removeChild(mobs[this.index_target].body);
                mobs.splice(this.index_target, 1);
                //this.min_distance = null;
                console.log(mobs);
            }
            stage.removeChild(this.bullet.body);
            this.bullet = null;
        }
        if (this.bullet) this.bullet.move();
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/korolariya/pen/VvwYvr

Comment: Мой FireFox нещадно крэшится (уже 4 раза попробовал) при открытии этого codepen'а ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Sergiks у меня норм http://prntscr.com/8b09e0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно логику игры завязывать на `requestAnimationFrame`.
Отрисовка сцены и игровые расчеты это разные вещи.

В функции `animate` нужно оставить только отрисовку текущего состояни сцены, а её измение должно происходить независимо от отрисовки (которой вообще может и не быть)

Например, пусть `tower` создает свой собственный таймер (со своим интервалом), по которому она будет проверять мобов, исходя из своих параметров (например, уровня, типа и т.п.) и пусть по этому таймеру запускается функция `find_mob`. Таким образом, к примеру, башню можно будет заморозить и она просто перестанет стрелять т.к. выключиться её внутренний таймер, или он будет работать по другому интервалу независимо от других элементов игры.

Comment: Спасибо дельный совет

Comment: Если я правильно внял совету то как то так получается http://codepen.io/korolariya/pen/zvYpNB

Comment: Да, все верно! Пара предложений в догонку:
1. вызов функции `mob.animate` так же лучше возложить на сам объект `mob` (со своим внутренним таймером).
2. я бы реализовал внутренний таймер [так](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPoExL?editors=001)

Comment: О! спасибо интересный подход, так же делаю в некоторых других проектах не связанных с играми и таймерами, и когда тут на вопросах привел код поставили минус, типо не паттерн, но с таймерами интересно выглядит, попробую писать в таком духе.