# Подскажите библиотеку которой в js можно управлять нажатиями клавиш

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

Ищу библиотеку которая бы нормально бы обрабатывала нажатия клавиш.
Например я нажимаю клавишу A потом нажимаю клавишу W  и персонаж должен передвигаться влево и вверх. 
Возможно я изначально не правильно пытаюсь перемещать персонажа.
Скрипт срабатывает так, нажимаю влево он перемещается влево, нажимаю вверх останавливается, потом если есть скрипт A+W то он с задержкой перемещается вверх. И получается если наоборот я бегу вверх потом нажимаю влево то должен быть скрипт W+A. 
Когда нажимаю W+D вообще нет движения.
Вот пример кода:

```
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(800, 600);



$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append(renderer.view);
    $('body').click(function(e) {
        player.target.x = e.clientX;
        player.target.y = e.clientY;
        player.distance();
        player.active_move = 1;
    });

    $('body').mousemove(function(e) {
        player.target.x = e.clientX;
        player.target.y = e.clientY;
        player.loock();
    });

    $(document).keyboard(
        'a',
        function(e, bind) {
            // player.body.position.x -= 1;
            player.left = 1;
        }
    );
    $(document).keyboard(
        's',
        function(e, bind) {
            player.down = 1;
        }
    );
    $(document).keyboard(
        'w',
        function(e, bind) {
            player.top = 1;
        }
    );
    $(document).keyboard(
        'd',
        function(e, bind) {
            player.right = 1;
        }
    );
    $(document).keyboard(
        'a+s',
        function(e, bind) {
            player.down = 1;
            player.left = 1;
        }
    );
    $(document).keyboard(
        's+d',
        function(e, bind) {
            player.right = 1;
            player.down = 1;
        }
    );
    $(document).keyboard(
        'w+a',
        function(e, bind) {
            player.top = 1;
            player.left = 1;
        }
    );
    $(document).keyboard(
        'w+d',
        function(e, bind) {
            player.top = 1;
            player.down = 1;
        }
    );

});


// create the root of the scene graph
var stage = new PIXI.Container();

PIXI.loader
    .add('frames/walck.json')
    .load(onAssetsLoaded);

var player;

function onAssetsLoaded() {
    // create an array to store the textures
    player = new player();

    // start animating
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}


function player() {
    this.hp = 100;
    this.level = 1;
    this.vector_to_target = {
        x: 100,
        y: 100
    };
    this.target = {
        x: 100,
        y: 100
    };
    this.speed = 1;
    this.body = null;
    this.texture = null;
    this.textures = [];
    this.active_move = 0;
    this.distance = function() {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.target.x - this.body.position.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.target.y - this.body.position.y, 2));
    }

    this.loock = function() {
        //Поворот
        this.vector_to_target.x = this.target.x - this.body.position.x;
        this.vector_to_target.y = this.target.y - this.body.position.y;
        this.body.rotation = Math.atan2(this.vector_to_target.y, this.vector_to_target.x);
    }
    this.move = function() {
        //Поворот
        this.vector_to_target.x = this.target.x - this.body.position.x;
        this.vector_to_target.y = this.target.y - this.body.position.y;
        this.body.rotation = Math.atan2(this.vector_to_target.y, this.vector_to_target.x);
        //Движение
        this.modul_target = Math.sqrt(this.vector_to_target.x * this.vector_to_target.x + this.vector_to_target.y * this.vector_to_target.y);
        this.body.position.x += this.speed * this.vector_to_target.x / this.modul_target;
        this.body.position.y += this.speed * this.vector_to_target.y / this.modul_target;
    }

    this.test_move = function(nav) {
        switch (nav) {
            case 'left':
                this.body.position.x -= 10;
                this.left = 0;
                break;
            case 'right':
                this.body.position.x += 10;
                this.right = 0;
                break;
            case 'top':
                this.body.position.y -= 10;
                this.top = 0;
                break;
            case 'down':
                this.body.position.y += 10;
                this.down = 0;
                break;
        }
    }


    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        this.texture = PIXI.Texture.fromFrame('walck' + i + '.png');
        this.textures.push(this.texture);
    }
    this.body = new PIXI.extras.MovieClip(this.textures);
    this.body.anchor = {
        x: 0.5,
        y: 0.5
    };
    this.body.position = {
        x: 200,
        y: 200
    };
    this.body.animationSpeed = 0.4;
    this.body.play();
    stage.addChild(this.body);
    setInterval(this.animate.bind(this), 10);
}



player.prototype.animate = function() {
    console.log(this.target);
    console.log(this.distance());
    if (this.distance() < 10)
        this.active_move = 0;
    if (this.right) {
        this.test_move('right');
    }
    if (this.left) {
        this.test_move('left');
    }
    if (this.top) {
        this.test_move('top');
    }
    if (this.down) {
        this.test_move('down');
    }



}



function animate() {
    renderer.render(stage);

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

Comment: @shatal, неправда.

Comment: Где на это посмотреть можно? По коду не могу угадать, что там не так. А клавиши надо самому обрабатывать и сохранять флаги. А всё движение - по таймеру.

Comment: @shatal, что за чушь? если руки прямые, то html5 подходит для геймдева очень даже хорошо. [Quake III](http://media.tojicode.com/q3bsp/), [Plus 360 Degrees](http://carvisualizer.plus360degrees.com/classics/), [Trigger Rally](https://triggerrally.com/track/RF87t6b6/drive). Еще нужны примеры?

Comment: Я конечно в геймдеве не специалист, но мне кажется что нужно слушать отдельно нажатия клавиши и её отжатие. При этом у игрока должен быть вектор скорости допустим `velocity`. Изначально он должен быть равен `[0, 0]` (то есть, стоим на месте). Так вот если нажать, например, клавишу `A`, то прибавляем к `velocity` вектор `[-1, 0]`. При отжатии `A`, вычитаем этот вектор, точно так же с остальными клавишами. При этом если нажать `A` и `W` к `velocity` прибавиться вектор `[-1, 0] + [0, 1] = [-1, 1]`.

Comment: @vihtor: например, в Unity на каждом кадре можно просто проверять, нажата ли клавиша. Этого достаточно, чтобы работать с продолжительным нажатием, а также детектировать момент нажатия и отжатия.

Comment: Комментарий из ответа: [посмотри пожалуйста эту библиотеку возможно она подойдёт](https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster)

Comment: зачем мешать логику игры с отрисовкой сцены? вот, например, [что](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/446153/179068) может получиться. с другой стороные вы предлагаете производить проверку нажатия клавиши 60+ раз в секунду. в моём примере, можно отреагировать на нажатие клавиши один раз и начать плавно увеличивать этот вектор. в итоге получиться плавное ускорение.

Comment: @vihtor делал так потом решил упростить, для примера, устанавливал точку куда должен двигаться персонаж, а он уже туда перемещался. Думаю с вектором будет в дальнейшем, но тут можно было свести к сообщениям в консоль действия по нажатию кнопок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна не "библиотека которая бы нормально бы обрабатывала нажатия клавиш", а самому нормально обрабатывать эти нажатия.

есть текущая позиция объекта `position = [100, 100]`, есть его вектор скорости `velocity = [0, 0]`. на нажатие просто меняем вектор скорости.

[Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/181g794f/) рабочий пример

Comment: Благодарствую, сенсей =) идеально, допишу игру напишу спасибо где нить в уголке

Comment: Все получилось даже лучше чем ожидал =)  http://smartcook.info/testgame/test1.html

Comment: Неплохо! Сейчас сразу можно заместить что по диагонали игрок движется быстрее чем по осям. И, например, в [Crimsonland](http://www.crimsonland.com/) игрок может двигаться и смотреть в разных направлениях, по этому там разделили игрока на верхную часть (голова, плечи и руки) и нижнюю (ноги), которые вращаются независимо

Comment: да заметил тоже, я планирую так же разделить будет состоять из 2-х мувиклипов, я просто планирую на nodejs сделать основу потом начну рисовать и допиливать анимации.

Answer (score 0):

посмотри пожалуйста эту библиотеку возможно она подойдёт: [keymaster](https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster)
1. подключи библиотеку 
2. используй нужные сочетания клавиш `key('a+w', function(){ alert('you pressed a!') });`

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. Спасибо за ваш ответ! Тут такое дело: ответы из одной ссылки обычно не считаются хорошими ответами. Они обычно получаются на вопросы, в которых автор просит найти для него какой-то софт (как в этом случае), что тоже не одобряется. Поэтому просто ссылки публикуются в комментариях.

Comment: Если вы можете дополнить ответ примером того, как автору в его коде использовать эту библиотеку, было бы очень здорово.

Comment: Было бы неплохо пример с нажатием 2-х клавиш, только не CTRL, Shift, а например A+W

Comment: принято, благодарю.следующий раз обещаю учитывать правила, и писать развёрнутые комментарии и ответы.