# Зачем всем сдался requestAnimationFrame вместо таймера?

Tags: javascript, анимация, setinterval

Собственно, речь об [этом ответе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/529361/178988).

Есть такой [комментарий](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529359/%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-javascript/529361?noredirect=1#comment659364_529361) с +2

> Угу. Это конечно хорошо, но с интервалом есть проблемы некоторые, и для таких целей вроде как есть requestAnimationFrame ..... все равно велосипеды - как-то не стоит изобретать, имхо)) – Алексей Шиманский 12 часов назад

И ещё такой:

> Перепишите ответ через requestAnimationFrame иначе придется поставить минус. Да и заодно уже через вектор. – Serge Esmanovich 32 мин. назад

В чём *в данном случае* преимущество `requestAnimationFrame`?

Таймер даёт мне 10 шагов в секунду, плавность перемещения обеспечивается за счёт `transition` в css. `requestAnimationFrame` по возможности даст 60 кадров в секунду и высокоточное значение времени, по идее позволяющее точно вычислить точное положение. Но зачем мне сдалось точное положение при перемещении по клеткам? И зачем мне считать его самому, если `transition`а вполне достаточно?

Comment: странно, [тут тоже без объяснений](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935262/settimeout-or-setinterval-or-requestanimationframe) :)

Comment: Если конкретно в том маленьком никчемном примере, то вполне....Но не думаю, что игры на canvas используют 10 строк кода, в котором как раз СетИнтервал убьет всё к чертям (а ведь автор делает именно игру, а не финтяфлюху на 10 строк).........я писал в общем, а не конкретно про пример, если чО. Но в целом вы сподвигаете опять того же новичка сделать ошибку, чтоб он делал неправильно... имхо - нужно хотя бы оговорочку про `requestAnimationFrame` написать.

Answer (score 10):

Во-первых, SetTimeout не принимает во внимание то, что еще происходит в браузере. Страница может, например, находится в неактивной вкладке браузера. При этом она будет использовать ресурсы процессора не взирая на это.

Кстати умный Chrome делает setInterval и setTimeout равным 1fps в скрытых вкладках.. но, насколько я знаю, так пока делает только chrome :(

Во-вторых, SetTimeout требует перерисовки страницы не в то же время, когда это делает ваш компьютер (а он делает это регулярно). Это означает, что ваш бедный браузер должен синхронизировать вашу горе-анимацию с обновлением всего экрана, и если ее частота не синхронизирована с обновлением всего экрана, это может потребовать больше вычислительной мощности. А это загрузка процессора, нагрев, шум куллера, расход батареи мобильных девайсов.. и т.п

Еще одним аспектом является анимации нескольких элементов сразу. Конечно, можно попытаться все это синхронизировать, но .. это очередной кошмар, в случае разноплановой анимации, происходящей одновремменно.

Чтобы преодолеть эти проблемы, Mozilla (создатели Firefox) предложил функцию requestAnimationFrame, которая впоследствии была принята и усовершенствована командой WebKit (Chrome и Safari). Она обеспечивает встроеный API для запуска любых типов анимации в браузере (DOM элементов, canvas, WebGL и др.)

```
function step() {
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
  // описываем один шаганимации тут
}
step();
```

Шикарно! Это же, как setTimeout, приведенный выше, но с requestAnimationFrame вместо него!!! При желании вы можете передать еще один параметр – анимируемый элемент: requestAnimationFrame(step, element);

Однако, как вы могли заметить, мы не указали интервал. Как часто бдет вызываться наша функция? Все зависит от частоты кадров вашего браузера и компьютера (обычно это 60 кадров в секунду). Ключевым отличием является то, что вы просите браузер выполнить функцию (в нашем примере step) при первой возможности, а не с заданным интервалом. Еще одно достоинство такого подхода в том, что браузеры могут снизить requestAnimationFrame в зависимости от нагрузки, видимости элемента и состояния батареи.

Еще несколько неоценимых достоинств requestAnimationFrame, в том, что он будет группировать все ваши анимации в одном браузерном repaint. Это сэкономит ресурсы процессора и позволяет вашему устройству быть быстрее и жить дольше.

Если вы используете requestAnimationFrame, все ваши анимации будут гладкими и красивыми, синхронизированными с вашим графическим процессором (GPU) и съедающими гораздо меньше ресурсов центрального процессора (CPU).

Источник http://html5.by/blog/what-is-requestanimationframe/

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/529630/178988

Answer (score -1):

> Во-первых, SetTimeout не принимает во внимание то, что еще происходит в браузере.

Да, но есть некоторые но, так что продолжим.

> Страница может, например, находится в неактивной вкладке браузера. При этом она будет использовать ресурсы процессора не взирая на это.

Вот есть игра в которой что-то происходит, на игрока кто-то нападает. Пользователь не нажимая паузу перейдёт на другую вкладку, чтобы его съели? Вряд ли. А если да, то он это делает намеренно и это его выбор.

> Кстати умный Chrome делает setInterval и setTimeout равным 1fps в скрытых вкладках.. но, насколько я знаю, так пока делает только chrome :(

`setInterval` и `setTimeout` вообще не гарантируют точность. Функция вызовется через заданное время или позже - и это всё, что про него известно.

> Во-вторых, SetTimeout требует перерисовки страницы не в то же время, когда это делает ваш компьютер (а он делает это регулярно).

`setTimeout` ничего не требует. Мой код представляет логику игры, а не отрисовку. Раз в 100 мс игрок выполняет переход в другую клетку.

Это изменение прописывается в трансформацию элемента, но ничего не считывается. Это не форсирует ни перерисовку, ни перерасчёт значений. Браузер сам выполнит отрисовку по своему расписанию.

> Это означает, что ваш бедный браузер должен синхронизировать вашу горе-анимацию с обновлением всего экрана, и если ее частота не синхронизирована с обновлением всего экрана, это может потребовать больше вычислительной мощности. А это загрузка процессора, нагрев, шум куллера, расход батареи мобильных девайсов.. и т.п

Нет. Я не реализую анимацию на js. Js изменяет состояние игры после шага и записывает его. Браузер делает перерисовку независимо от этого тогда, когда посчитает нужным. Плавность обеспечивается css-анимацией, которую браузер контролирует сам.

Кроме того, изменяется `transform`, являющийся наиболее лёгким для браузера.

> Еще одним аспектом является анимации нескольких элементов сразу. Конечно, можно попытаться все это синхронизировать, но .. это очередной кошмар, в случае разноплановой анимации, происходящей одновремменно.

Это не относится к примеру.

При большом числе объектов с разными параметрами и делается отрисовка на canvas'е, то можно использовать те же `setTimeout`ы, но внутри них выполнять только сохранение состояния игры. А непосредственно отрисовку выполнять для всего состояния в отдельном `requestAnimationFrame`.

> Чтобы преодолеть эти проблемы, Mozilla (создатели Firefox) предложил функцию requestAnimationFrame, которая впоследствии была принята и усовершенствована командой WebKit (Chrome и Safari). Она обеспечивает встроеный API для запуска любых типов анимации в браузере (DOM элементов, canvas, WebGL и др.)

Да, она предназначена для выполнения действий, связанных с отрисовкой. Она передаёт значение высокоточного таймера, позволяющее точно просчитать, какое перемещение следует сделать. Она позволяет эффективно использовать ресурсы для отрисовки.

Но какое всё это имеет отношение к конкретному примеру, где есть таймер, реализующий **логику** игры? В данном примере нет причин переносить логику в `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: **реализующий логику игры** - то есть `$div.css('transform', translate(${x}px, ${y}px));` как бы не причем? Ну ок.)) ... а в MSDN наверное дураки сидят раз запхали такую логику в requestAnimationFrame https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh920765(v=vs.85).aspx   Надо написать им))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, css-стиль - это тоже состояние. И я не вижу смысла городить отдельную логику для отрисовки в данном примере. Тем более, присваивание transform не вызывает немедленную перерисовку или перерасчёт.

Comment: @Qwertiy ты уже готов к тому чтобы написать свой браузер, дерзай

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, а почему ты не напишешь ответ в том вопросе? Тем более, ты уже делал [нечто подобное](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453912/178988).

Comment: @Qwertiy сейчас пару минут, что нить чиркану, работаю просто